# Can a journal once removed from Scopus be reindexed in Scopus?

Tags: indexing

If a journal indexing in Scopus is cancelled, can such journal be indexed in Scopus again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, provided the reasons that led to delisting are addressed.